# ax 2009/2012 development environment for self trying?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

I am a junior AX functional consultant and am interested also in developing - just as a way to better understanding of how AX works.
I have prior programming knowledge (but only Java Core), and read now the book "Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 Programming: Getting Started" of E.Dalen. 
So far it is pretty understandable for me, but I would like to try some code examples on my own.

I wonder,if there is development environment for AX that I can download personally on my PC for this purpose?

Of course,I could ask it at my work, but would like avoid questions from their side for at least now, because I am functional consultant and not a developer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at [free trial microsoft dyanmics AX 2012 R2](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/105316)

Comment: thank you! seems i have to use MS partner source